# Convert str into float but problems with multiple dots in numbers

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, floating-point

I downloaded this datafile from the TCGA database but I am not sure how to process it in python. After importing it with pd.read_csv, I wanted to convert the `reads_per_million_miRNA_mapped` column to floats, as they are strings now, but it gives me the following error can't be done because of the dots.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.024.089'
```

The txt file looks like this:

```
    miRNA_ID        read_count  reads_per_million_miRNA_mapped
    hsa-mir-1227    1           0.204818    
    hsa-mir-1228    5           1.024.089   
    hsa-mir-1229    12          2.457.814
```

So I was thinking to remove the dots, but then you get the problem of also removing dots that act like commas, like `0.204818`.

EDIT:
I think the best solution for this would be do remove the dots except if there are more than 3 numbers behind a dot (so `0.204818` would be an exception). Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, what horrific formatting.  How are you supposed to guess whether `1.024` is "one thousand twenty-four" or "one point zero two four" if they use decimal points ambiguously like that?

Comment: ```2.457.814``` - How do you read this ? Is it same as ```2,457,814``` ?

Comment: @Ram I think so. And if there are more than 3 numbers behind the dots then it's read as a comma.. At least that's what I think

Comment: The thousands separator in many locations is a period, not a comma as it is in the USA. You may need to set or specify the proper locale before or when reading the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all numbers will be floats (i.e. the last dot acts as a decimal point), you can get rid of all but the last dot and then cast into floats:

```
example = '1.024.089'
num = example.replace('.', '', example.count('.') - 1)
print(float(num))
```

Output:

```
1024.089
```

EDIT:

To check whether there are more than 3 numbers after the last/only dot you can do something like this:

```
i = num.index('.')
digits_after_dot = len(num[i+1:])
```

Example:

```
num = '12.12345'
i = num.index('.')
digits_after_dot = len(num[i+1:])
print(digits_after_dot)
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Thanks! But now that I have thought about it, I think I'd rather have a solution that takes into account whether there are more than 3 numbers after the last/only "dot"

Comment: You could get the index of the last/only dot with `num.index('.')` and then use `len()` and slicing to count whether there are more than 3 numbers.

Comment: Oh that's great! Could you pretty please update your code and show me? I am not so good yet at python (oops)

Comment: Yeah, I added some details.